# How to select the mq-deadline scheduler?

Tags: linux, scheduling, block-device

I'm trying to select the new mq-deadline io scheduler but it doesn't seem available.

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler 
noop [deadline]
```

kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux pluto 4.11.6-zenbook #1 SMP Wed Jun 21 09:39:34 EDT 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg:

```
$ sudo dmesg|grep deadline
[    0.077863] TSC deadline timer enabled
[    1.383260] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    1.383261] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to enable `CONFIG_SCSI_MQ_DEFAULT`

```
Symbol: SCSI_MQ_DEFAULT [=y]
Type  : boolean
Prompt: SCSI: use blk-mq I/O path by default
  Location:
    -> Device Drivers
      -> SCSI device support
  Defined at drivers/scsi/Kconfig:50
  Depends on: SCSI [=y]
```

And voila

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to specify theses parameters on the kernel command line :

```
scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 elevator=mq-deadline
```

Source : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/improving_performance#Changing_I.2FO_scheduler

Comment: This is partly correct. Currently (up to kernel 5.0.0) it is not possible to change the scheduler when using blk-mq using a boot parameter, so `elevator=mq-deadline` will have no effect. Note that in that particular case it might look like it is working, on my box `mq-deadline` is the one picked up by default eventhough I have BFQ and None compiled in kernel.